# Salesforce package fails to install custom fields

Tags: package

I created a custom package, which makes custom fields on the Salesforce order object. The package installed the fields, but the API name is incorrect.

On my development environment, the API name is

connexqb__Balance__c

In the Salesforce for my customer, the field name is Balance__c. Why was connexqb__ omitted? Here is the package install:

https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t1R000000kXzy

Here is my set-up:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your package `Connex Order Custom Fields` is an unmanaged, non-namespaced package. This is the expected behavior when you install it in an org.

Your managed package is `Connex for QuickBooks`. Only the components in that package will be namespaced. You can tell by the icon next to its package listing, and because your packaging org shows

> Managed Package:   Connex for QuickBooks

If you want your other packages to be namespaced, you'd need to build separate 1GP managed packages in different packaging orgs, or use second-generation packages to build either managed packages or unlocked packages with a namespace.

Comment: OK, so in my org custom fields will have namespaces and in other orgs there will be no namespace?

Comment: It's about whether or not they are packaged or in a packaging org.